# The method getBackMysql() is undefined for the type JSONObject

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am now writing a java program to fetch back data in Mysql database. Sure to have read all the posts concerning about this issue (still cannot figure out), and I have included org.json.jar in my reference library.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.json.*;


public class getBackMysql
{
    static final String JDBC_Driver = ...;
    static final String DB_URL = ...;

    static final String USER = ...;
    static final String PASS = ...;

    public static JSONObject jsonobject;

    public static JSONObject getBackMysql()
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting the Database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection( DB_URL, USER, PASS );

            System.out.println("Instantiating Statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT t, obtid FROM t_localobtmind where obtid = 'G3742' order by ddatetime desc limit 1;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                String obtid = rs.getString("obtid");
                int temp = rs.getInt("t");

                String temperature = (String)("Temperature: " + temp / 10 + "℃");

                jsonobject.put("obtid", obtid);
                jsonobject.put("temperature", temperature);
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        }

        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (stmt != null)
                {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException se2)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    System.out.println("----Program ends----");
    return jsonobject;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {

        JSONObject json = json.getBackMysql();
        int tmp = json.getInt("temperature");
        String obtid = json.getString("obtid");


    }
}
```

Eclipse shows me the following error: The method getBackMysql() is undefined for the type JSONObject. I am still fresh to JSONObject and have no idea what's going on. I have changed the class name for several times, but it does not work. Plus, it's a small test before a larger project.

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paster your complete code along with file name for each of the above code snippet

Comment: Modified. Only one file "getBackMysql.java".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` class does not `getBackMysql()` method, so we can't access it from object of `JSONObject` class.

Since getBackMysql() is within the same class where main method is present. You can replace the line

```
JSONObject json=json.getBackMysql();
```

With

```
JSONObject json=getBackMysql();
```

Comment: Once I do such replacements, the program throws Unhandled exception type JSONException and asks me to surround the code with try & catch.

Comment: add JSONException class in catch block, in the sam way you did it for SQLException and Exception class